# What the author really want to say

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read the article "The Myth of Main Street" on the [New York Times website](https://mobile.nytimes.com/2017/04/08/opinion/sunday/the-myth-of-main-street.html). I am not clear about below:

> This nostalgia, like the frustration that underlies it, has a long and instructive history. Years before deindustrialization, years before Nafta, Americans were yearning for a Main Street that never quite existed.

Main Street existed from 19th century (a few decades in the 19th century, as said in this article), and Main Street expired in 1960 or 1970. NAFTA was signed in 1994, deindustrialization is in 20th century. Before the deindustrialization and NAFTA, Main Street has already existed for a long time.

Why does the author write "Years before deindustrialization, years before Nafta, Americans were yearning for a Main Street that never quite existed"?

I quite don't understand.

[full article here](https://mobile.nytimes.com/2017/04/08/opinion/sunday/the-myth-of-main-street.html)

Comment: I encourage you to write about your own understanding of the answer before anybody answers this question so as to not elicit a negative response from the community :)

Comment: The "*Main Street that never quite existed*" is an **imagined** one - mythical. That's one of the main points of the article.

Comment: @satnam Do you have any idea about this question?

Comment: What do you mean by _"... Main Street has already existed for a long time"_? That's not part of the article, so you're just asserting ... something. But what Main Street are you talking about?

Comment: What Main Street I mean is the physical shopping Street. I will give you the picture.

Comment: https://mobile.nytimes.com/2017/04/08/opinion/sunday/the-myth-of-main-street.html#modal-lightbox

Comment: "Main Street" is a concept, not a physical entity.

Comment: (Consider that there are likely thousands of streets named "Main Street" in the US.)

Comment: I yearn for old-fashioned nostalgia.  I don't like this newfangled stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Janet, the author means something a lot like 'Main Street in any real town wasn't what you see portrayed in *Gunsmoke* or *Rawhide*, *Bonanza* or *The High Chaparral*, *Dr Quin Medicine Woman*, *Wyatt Earp*, *High Noon* or *The Gunfight at The OK Corral*, nor even *Waterhole #3*.'

Generically, none of those paints a really bad picture but in specific detail, any of them can be quite misleading…

Answer (score -1):

As the author introduced the long and instructive history of Main Street, Main Street existed with the people paying higher price than it should be. But in hard-pressed rural communities and small towns, people cannot afford it. The ideal Main Street should be low-price, which small- town Americans can afford . That's why The Americans were yearning for a Main Street that never quite existed. The ideal Main Street the Americans are yearning for is a sustainable one, price- favorable one.

I am not quite sure about what I got . Hope to get more answers.